# Using EventAggregator to communicate between WPF in ElementHost and host WinForm

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Can I use the [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649187.aspx) to subscribe to events in a WinForm published from a ViewModel?

I need to change the properties of a WinForm that hosts a WPF composite application in an ElementHost from a module of the WPF composite application as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893589/changing-host-winform-properties-from-viewmodel-bound-to-elementhost).

I thought that to solve this problem I could use the EventAggregator to publish events in a ViewModel that would be subscribed to by the WinForm. The arguments of this event could include the things I want to change on the WinForm like the title.

I've read through the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921173%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649187.aspx

But I still can't work out if the EventAggregator is fit for purpose in this situation.

[image: Event Aggregator]

Comment: Yes, I've used a message bus for communicating between MVVM WPF UI and a WinForms MVP UI in the same application. The WinForms portion was a third party charting control.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you happen to have any code you can post that demonstrates this communication? My ViewModel is not coupled to the WinForm. I'm trying to determine how to best change the properties of that WinForm from the ViewModel without having to create additional dependencies. I'm was hoping the Prism EventAggregator might allow me to do it via events but I'm having difficulty understanding how to use it at the moment.

Comment: I'm not a fan of prism. Look at MVVM light's version. I don't really have much in the way of code that I can share (corporate clients), but if you can share your repo, I'll gladly send you a simple changeset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of these components are in the same process then yes, you can use the `EventAggregator`.

Just remember that you'd have to reference **the same** instance of the aggregator in the publisher and the subscriber - the aggregator should be a singleton or be put in an IoC container as a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up using an EventAggregator. Here's the code in VB.NET as that's what I'm using for this particular project.

**1. EventAggregatorSingleton**

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Events

Public Class EventAggregatorSingleton

Private Shared _currentEventAggregator As EventAggregator
Private Shared _syncLock As Object = New Object()

Public Shared ReadOnly Property CurrentEventAggregator As EventAggregator
    Get
        If _currentEventAggregator Is Nothing Then
            SyncLock _syncLock
                If _currentEventAggregator Is Nothing Then
                    Dim currEventAggregator As New EventAggregator
                    _currentEventAggregator = currEventAggregator
                End If
            End SyncLock
        End If
        Return _currentEventAggregator
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

**2. Event Class**

```
Public Class ChartWizardPageChangedEvent
Inherits CompositePresentationEvent(Of WpfHostForm)

End Class
```

**3. Publish Event from ViewModel**

```
EventAggregatorSingleton.CurrentEventAggregator.GetEvent(Of ChartWizardPageChangedEvent)().Publish(_chartWizard)
```

**4. Subscribe to Event from WinForm**

```
EventAggregatorSingleton.CurrentEventAggregator.GetEvent(Of ChartWizardPageChangedEvent)().Subscribe(New Action(Of WpfHostForm)(AddressOf App_HostFormChanged))
```